# Multiple "unused" Views displays

Tags: 7, views

I'm creating a heavily customised website in Drupal. I want to use Views as a data source for a page with several options, where each option corresponds to a different display in a View. The reason I want to use Views is that they are easily configurable through a UI, so they are easy to tweak/change later if the need arises.

Unfortunately though, it seems like I can't create a display of a view that doesn't have some form of side effect (ie, a page display will create a new page). Does anyone have any bright ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/embed_views  "This is a views display based on the default views display that does not have any additional features or "cruft" that you can use to create embed views for your site."

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't just "unpublish" a view...

My suggestion would be to set the "access" setting of a view and make it only acessible for your own user or an admin role, that way its there but no-one can access it.

Comment: I suppose what I was looking for was a different display type provided by a third-party module that doesn't have any side effects.

Comment: Attachments have zero side effects :)

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a view in code as well. You'd want to edit your template.php file and in hook_preprocess_page or hook_preprocess_node (depending on what you're actually adding the views to) you can embed a view with the following snippet:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // check $variables for your particular page
  ...
  // embed a particular view's default display
  $variables['embeded_view'] = views_embed_view('view_name', 'default');
}
```

In the example I've created a new variable ('embeded_view') which can then be printed in your page's tpl file.

Comment: I know how to embed it, the issue was I can't create multiple displays of the same view without creating extra pages/blocks/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I often create multiple page displays that go to the same page.  Does only one path is added (that should solve your problem)

Then I take advantage of the fact that Views always returns the first display that the user has access to.  so I make sure that add restrictions in accordance to that rule.

So if if I have an admin-type display and a regular display, I make sure that the admin display is first and the regular display is second.  I add a restriction to the first one and add no restriction to the second one.

Comment: I'm embedding the views, not using a normal view page so this doesn't help since I want **no** pages created.